How to delete git repository of one specific solution in VS2022?
I have serveral solutions in VS2022 and each has a long git commit histories. Now I want to delete the git reporsitory of one my solution(for example solution A, but keep current latest source code) without affecting other solution's git reporsitories. I still want to keep the latest version of my solution A source code as a fresh starting point for future work before removing the commits. How can I do that? Any help with be appreciated!

To delete the git repository for a particular folder, just delete the .git folder inside, this contains the entire git repository for that folder. The folder might be hidden, though, so you might need to configure Finder or Windows Explorer to show hidden files and folders before you can see it. I leave this as a comment, because I've got a nagging feeling the question might have complex undertones not mentioned, such as possibly that you have one big repository with all your solutions in it, in which the approach becomes something entirely different.

Followied your instruction, I found the .git within my target solution folder. Just delete the .git folder, I got what I want. Thanks!

Left an answer, do read it as well, I mention some extra files you might want to consider as well.

In order to delete the local git repository of a folder, you have to find and delete the .git folder that is stored inside.
This houses your entire repository, meaning history, branches, tags, etc.
The source code of your project lives outside of this folder, so deleting the .git folder should be safe according to your question.
Note that this folder might be hidden, depending on configuration and which operating system you're on, so you might have to configure Finder or Windows Explorer (or whatever) to show hidden files and folders before you can see it.
Note that there might be files stored outside of the .git folder that might "belong" to the fact that used to be a git repository there, namely files like:

.gitattributes
.gitignore

(note, just those two, not all files starting with a .)
If you think you might want to create a new git repository for your folder at a later date, these files can be safely left alone, but they will probably not be used by anything else, so if you don't intend to create such a repository, you can probably delete these as well.
